# Outlook Add-In Forward Selected Email

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I am new to creating Office Add-Ins and having some problems. I am trying to create an Add-In that forwards the content of the currently selected email. as an attachment preferably, to a different email address.

I am trying to create this using a **Web Add-In**. I have gone through quite a few other posts on here and Microsoft documentation and have found out of one of sending an email using EWS; however, I cannot figure out how to send the content as an attachment.

```
function sendEmail() {
    var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    var request = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
        '  <soap:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" /></soap:Header>' +
        '  <soap:Body>' +
        '    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">' +
        '      <m:SavedItemFolderId><t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems" /></m:SavedItemFolderId>' +
        '      <m:Items>' +
        '        <t:Message>' +
        '          <t:Subject>' + item.subject + '</t:Subject>' +
        '          <t:Body BodyType="HTML">Hello World!</t:Body>' +
        '          <t:ToRecipients>' +
        '            <t:Mailbox><t:EmailAddress>' + Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress + '</t:EmailAddress></t:Mailbox>' +
        '          </t:ToRecipients>' +
        '        </t:Message>' +
        '      </m:Items>' +
        '    </m:CreateItem>' +
        '  </soap:Body>' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';

    Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
            console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Message sent!");
        }
    });
}
```

Has the functionality of sending emails been implemented within Office.js yet? Does anyone have any advice? I tried using VSTO but had constant issues with random crashing and the Add-In not showing up.

Thanks

Comment: You could try this.. <m:CreateAttachment><m:ParentItemId Id=X /><m:Attachments><t:ItemAttachment><t:Name>name</t:Name><t:IsInline>false</t:IsInline><t:Message><t:MimeContent CharacterSet="UTF-8">MimeContent</t:MimeContent></t:Message></t:ItemAttachment></m:Attachments></m:CreateAttachment>

Comment: @BrianClink Thanks for the reply! Could you possibly give me an example of this? I am trying to figure it out but am having no luck. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you need to create the item in drafts first, and then add the "message" attachment using MIME contents.  Sorry I can't give a sample.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll see what else I can dig up on this. Thanks!

Comment: Currently the feature of sending emails via OfficeJS API is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Alternatively, you can try what @Brian has suggested.